# Imagick dll for php 5.3?

Tags: php, imagick

Where I can get it (php_imagick.dll for win32)?
I don't have ability to compile it from src.

Comment: http://imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#windows

Comment: Thanks, I know that link. But I can't find .dll file after I install it.

Comment: an answer to this would have helped me, thank you for closing.. =/

Comment: Found the files here : http://valokuva.org/?p=197

Answer (score 1):

The folks at ImageMagick have released an official [Windows installer](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows), so finding the dll by itself might not be necessary.